# Python Flask application not deployable on AWS Elastic Beanstalk | No module named 'application'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Error message in web.stdout.log:

```
Oct 15 13:03:29 ip-172-31-18-218 web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
Oct 15 13:03:29 ip-172-31-18-218 web: [2020-10-15 13:03:29 +0000] [4633] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4633)
Oct 15 13:03:29 ip-172-31-18-218 web: [2020-10-15 13:03:29 +0000] [4626] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Oct 15 13:03:29 ip-172-31-18-218 web: [2020-10-15 13:03:29 +0000] [4626] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Error message in nginx/error.log

```
2020/10/15 13:04:21 [error] 4559#0: *19 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.42.151, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.18.218"
```

Flask app:

```
# EB looks for an 'application' callable by default.
application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/')
def home(): 
    return "Hello World"

@application.route('/processImage')
def index():
    [Some Code...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Setting debug to True enables debug output. This line should be
    # removed before deploying a production app.
    application.run('localhost',8000,debug=True)
```

requirements.txt

```
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.19.2
opencv-python==4.4.0.44
requests==2.24.0
urllib3==1.25.10
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

My folder structure:

```
eb-flask
  |- .vscode (folder)
  |- images (folder)
  |- application.py
  |- requirements.txt
```

Way of deployment:

```
Deployment via the Elastic Beanstalk Web UI by uploading a .zip archive of the above described folder.
```

Any ideas on how to further debug or solve this would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try `>set FLASK_APP=application.py`

Comment: Where should I do that setting?

Comment: Run that command using command line from your working directory.

Comment: @Shradha Unfortunatly this did not resolve the isse.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error.

Few things I did was:

1. Made a change: `application = app = Flask(__name__)`.
2. Renamed the python file to `application.py`.

**Also very important: whatever files are required select those and zip them (right-click "send to" -> "compressed" in windows) and upload to the beanstalk.**

**DO NOT put all the required files in a folder and zip. This was the reason behind** `ModuleNotFound: No Module name 'application'`.

Comment: I agree, the way files are zipped is the reason behind ModuleNotFound error

Answer (score 1):

You are running your application on port 8000. However, EB will [expect it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) on port 5000. So either you change the default port on the EB, your you modify your application to run on port 5000:

```
application.run('localhost', 5000,debug=True)
```

Comment: I was working/testing with port 5000 before as this is the default port of flask. 
However the EB logs show that the EC2 instance is listening to port 8000, that why I changed the port. Anyway, both ports did not work for me.

Comment: @LeonardMichalas If you ssh into the EB instance, can you `curl` your app from inside? Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the modules to the environments path variable so that the module lookup is sucessful. Run the following from a file/ command line-

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append("/path_to_your_app/eb-flask")
```

Comment: Thank you! As I am only uploading a .zip archive of my code to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I am not quite sure what the correct path would be. Do you have any idea on this?